# Windows System partition in a HD different from where BIOS boots

Tags: windows-7, boot, partitioning, mbr

This is a problem I solved some time ago with the bootmgr command without pain and without losing my BCDs, but the way it was working before intrigues me.

I have a SSD disk and a normal SATA disk. I installed a W7 on the SSD but, as I had a FreeDos on my SATA, I think the W7 installer used the FreeDos partition to store the bootmgr as it saw it was the only chainloader disposable, even if it was being installed on a different disk. That left me with a system partition on the SATA FreeDos partition and with the boot patition on my SSD when W7 was selected from the mgr menu.

If I was booting from the SSD. Does it mean my VBR was pointing to a bootmgr in a different disk? Is that even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> my VBR was pointing to a bootmgr in a different disk?

No. Assuming MBR partitioning (rather than UEFI), an entry in your BCD was pointing to a \Windows directory on a different disk.

The partition table in the MBR (block 0 of the disk, and not part of any partition) indicates where the primary partitions are and which one is "active". The code from the MBR loads the first block of the VBR from that partition and transfers control to that code.

The first block of the VBR code reads the rest of the VBR (for NTFS it's 8 blocks). The VBR doesn't "point to" any partition other than itself... at least, not with any VBR I ever heard of. But VBRs vary by OS and by file system type, so theoretically, this could happen.

Conventionally, though, the code from the VBR finds your OS boot loader (bootmgr for Windows Vista and later, ntldr for earlier versions of Windows) on the same partition the VBR came from, loads its first few blocks, and transfers control to that code. bootmgr then loads the rest of itself, and reads your BCD. It's the BCD entry that indicates which disk and partition from which to load the OS.

Note that the VBR code has to have a little knowledge of the file system on its own partition. In Windows it just has to be able to find files by name in the root directory, and read them. The code from ntldr or bootmgr has to be able to do the same for the boot volume, but has to understand subdirectories.

Comment: Thanks. So, how I ended up with my system partition on a different disk? The system partition on windows systems holds the bootmgr and the boot partition, this time on my SSD, holds the final files to be read to start Windows (pointed by the BCDs). The only thing I can think about is that in fact the BIOS was skipping my SSD and booting the SATA. Is there standards available to look for info apart of Wikipedia?

Comment: Being my BCD on the SATA, system partition, then it would be pointing to the init files on my SSD. So this means if this happens the HD that is really being booted from the BIOS is the SATA, not the SSD. Am I right?

Comment: It sounds as though your system was already configured to find an MBR on your hard drive, so Windows setup just left it at that. Once Windows setup can establish a system partition, it's really not a special case to put the boot partition anywhere. 
I don't know about standards, but much of this is standard legacy PC stuff going back decades. Windows specifics are of course in the various editions of _Windows Internals_. Yes, the drive being booted from the BIOS is the hard drive, not the SSD. (I imagine they're both "SATA"!)

Comment: Here's a Channel9 video on the Vista-and-later boot sequence. It doesn't cover everything but it's good stuff. http://channel9.msdn.com/shows/Going+Deep/Windows-Vista-PreOS-Environment-What-happens-before-the-OS-loads/